# displaying list vertically in html

Tags: html, css, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am getting a list from java side as [Pune, Mumbai, Delhi] .I want this to be displayed vertically . How can I do that . I wanted to do this in angular js ,but somehow the function is not getting called on click .
output I need -

```
Pune
Mumbai
Delhi
```

controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home.web", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/xml",
            "application/json" })

    public  ModelAndView getUSCity(@RequestParam ("statechoice") String statechoice) {


        List<String> msa = new ArrayList<String>();     
        msa = msaService.getMsaCodes(statechoice);

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Home");
        model.addObject("city",msa);


        return model;
    }
```

jsp after removing the ng directives for angular -

```
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>

<!-- <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function MyController($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getPersonDataFromServer = function() {
            alert("Hi");
            $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : 'home.web'
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(data);
                $scope.cities=data;

            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });

        };

    };
</script>
     -->
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">
    <h4>US map</h4>
    <div>
        <img src="images/usmap.gif" alt="US MAP" width="529" height="334"
            border='0' usemap='#usimage' align="middle">
    </div>
    <div>
        <map name='usimage'>
            <!--- BEGIN: East --->
            <area shape='polygon' coords='489,52,502,31,513,32,518,54,490,71'
                href='home.web?statechoice=ME' target="_self" alt='Maine'>
        </map>
    </div>
    <div>

        <table border="1" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <tr style="background-color: lightgray;">
                <th>Cities</th>
            <tr>
                <td>${city}</td>
            </tr>

            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

div tags when I was using angular ng-repeat .

```
   <body style="text-align: center;" data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="MyController">
<h4 > US map</h4>
<div>
<img src="images/usmap.gif" alt="US MAP" width="529" height="334" border='0' usemap='#usimage' align="middle">
</div>
<div>
<map name='usimage'>
            <!--- BEGIN: East --->
            <area shape='polygon' coords='489,52,502,31,513,32,518,54,490,71' data-ng-click="getPersonData()" href='home.web?statechoice=ME' target="_self"  alt='Maine'>
        </map>
        </div>
        <div>

            <table  border ="1" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <tr style="background-color:lightgray;">
                    <th>Cities</th>

                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="city in cities">{{city}}</li>
                </ul>

                </div>
</body>
</html>
```

updated - Function is gettng called now . The values are not getting updated though.

using routing -

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']). 
    module.config(function($routeProvider){
         $routeProvider
         .when('/home.web',{
                templateUrl: 'Views/Home.jsp',
         })
    })

    function MyController($scope, $http) {

        $scope.getPersonData = function() {         
            $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : 'home.web'
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(data);
                $scope.cities = data;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("error");
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });

        };

    };
</script>
```

Comment: I think you forget close tr tag

Comment: `<ul>` is not a valid child of `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

check this

https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=preview

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="city in cities">{{city}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My function is not getting called for some reason which I am not able to figure out .Thats why this is not giving any result .

Comment: Ok. I think you missed to include ng-controller="myCtrl" in html

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `</table>` and `</tr>`

```
  <table border="1" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <tr style="background-color: lightgray;">
      <th>Cities</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="city in cities">
      <td>{{city}}</td>
    </tr>
    <table>
```

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.cities=['Bengaluru','Mumbai','Hyderabad'];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h4>US map</h4>
<div>
  <img src="images/usmap.gif" alt="US MAP" width="529" height="334" border='0' usemap='#usimage' align="middle">
</div>
<div>
  <map name='usimage'>
    <!--- BEGIN: East --->
    <area shape='polygon' coords='489,52,502,31,513,32,518,54,490,71' href='home.web?statechoice=ME' target="_self" alt='Maine'>
  </map>
</div>
<div>

  <table border="1" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <tr style="background-color: lightgray;">
      <th>Cities</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="city in cities">
      <td>{{city}}</td>
    </tr>
    <table>
</div>
```

Remove ModelAndView from your code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home.web", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")

    public List<String> getUSCity(@RequestParam ("statechoice") String statechoice) {


        List<String> msa = new ArrayList<String>();     
        msa = msaService.getMsaCodes(statechoice);

        return msa;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks . This is working fine . I guess the problem in my code is from the spring mvc side .I dont know how to send data to angular from java side

Comment: @themaster post the issue. will help you.

Comment: Hi ,I have pasted the controller code as well . I have put alert on error in angular js fnc . When I am clicking ,it is going to the error part instead of success .Is there anything else you need

Comment: Do we use modelAndView object in this fashion when using angular js?

Comment: When I am removing the modelAndView ,it displays the value as ["Pune","Mumbai","Delhi"] in whole page .The existing page with a map is gone . Probably due to changing of URL . I want the values to be updated on the same page .Reason I tried using model and view so that I can reopen the same page

Comment: @themaster that you should take care in Angular routing. Accept the answer if it resolves your issue.

Comment: Could you please give an example how do I use angular routing .

Comment: @themaster https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route and https://www.consolelog.io/angularjs-change-path-without-reloading

Comment: Hi , thanks for links . I have updated my question with using routing . I tried using ng route .it says Views/home.jsp resource is unavailable .the path showing is correct . Can you help me here . Am I using routing correctly ?

Comment: @themaster ask a new question. Expecting to change the whole scope of the question to something else after someone answers original question is unrealistic

Comment: @themaster create a separate question if your are still facing an issue.